# How to get the x and y coordinates of mouse in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, mouse

```
from tkinter import *


def customMouse(e=None):
    x = e.x
    y = e.y
    label.place_configure(x=x,y=y-20)
root = Tk()
label = Label(master=root,text="^")
label.place(x=0,y=0)

root.bind('<Motion>',customMouse)

root.mainloop()
```

My problem is simple:
When I use `e.x` or `e.y` this returns the `x` and `y` coordinates of the mouse according to the widget over which the mouse is.
Also, I try using `e.x_root` and `e.y_root` this will return the mouse position of the desktop, not the Tkinter window.

My expected Output is that whenever my mouse moves then the `label` will place on the mouse's position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we subtract the coordinates of the upper left corner from the e.x ,y _root coordinates, then the label remains on the screen.

```
from tkinter import *


def customMouse(e=None):
    x = e.x_root - root.winfo_x() - 10
    y = e.y_root - root.winfo_y() - 40
    print(x, y)
    label.place_configure(x=x, y=y)


root = Tk()
label = Label(master=root, text="^", bg="grey")
label.place(x=0, y=0)

root.bind('<Motion>', customMouse)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have edited a bit now it's fine. Also thanks for the help.